# What is this CVS command doing?

Tags: syntax, cvs

I have been scouring the CVS man page for a while now, but am not able to follow what this CVS command is meant to do exactly. There appears to be multiple listings for -F in the man page, Im not sure if this is being used to specify a log file or regex or what. Is it merging `${newTag}` into `${mainTag}` or is constantPerl the tag? mainTag is defined as 'Production' and newTag is passed in as an argument to the script that runs this:

`cvs -d /home/main/cvs rtag -r ${newTag} -F ${mainTag} constantPerl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CVS has two kinds of options, global options and command options.

The form of a cvs command is:

```
cvs [ GLOBAL_OPTIONS ] COMMAND [ COMMAND_OPTIONS ] [ COMMAND_ARGS ]
```

In your case

```
cvs -d /home/main/cvs rtag -r ${newTag} -F ${mainTag} constantPerl
```

the COMMAND is `rtag`. You can tell from that that

```
-d /home/main/cvs
```

is a global option (that can apply to any cvs command) and that

```
-r ${newTag}
```

and

```
-F ${mainTag}
```

are command options, specific to the `rtag` command. Anything between the `cvs` command and the sub-command name (`rtag`, `log`, etc.) is a global option; anything following the sub-command name is a command option or a command argument.

In the CVS documentation (`info cvs`), go to the "Invoking CVS" section and search for `rtag`, where you'll find the following:

> '`-r TAG[:DATE]`'
>             Tag the revision already tagged with TAG or, when DATE is
>             specified and TAG is a branch tag, the version from the branch
>             TAG as it existed on DATE.  See *note Tagging by date/tag::
>             and *note Common options::.

and:

> '`-F`'
>   Move TAG if it already exists.  See *note Modifying tags::.